# Xcode updating label text from function

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I'm having trouble with some objective-c in Xcode. I'm trying to adapt an example from the DiskArbitration framework, and I'm getting stuck.  This example sets a callback whenever the framework sees a disk. From the callback, I want to update a label.

```
@interface AVRecorderDocument ()
    @property (assign) IBOutlet NSTextField *labelSpaceLeft;
@end

@implementation AVRecorderDocument
....

-id(init){
...
    DASessionRef sessionDA = DASessionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
    DARegisterDiskAppearedCallback(sessionDA, kDADiskDescriptionMatchVolumeMountable, diskAppearedCallback, 0);
    DASessionScheduleWithRunLoop(sessionDA, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
...
}


static void diskAppearedCallback(DADiskRef disk, void* context)
{
    CFDictionaryRef description = DADiskCopyDescription(disk);
    NSLog(@"Disk appeared: %@", description);
    NSLog(@"Disk Name: %@", CFDictionaryGetValue(description, CFSTR("DADeviceModel")));

//  [_labelSpaceLeft setStringValue:[NSString CFDictionaryGetValue(description, CFSTR("DADeviceModel"))]];


    CFRelease(description);
}
...
@end
```

The commented line inside the static function is what i've tried, but I get a "Use of undeclared identifier" error.

I've also tried converting the function to a method, which the compiler is ok with, but then I don't know how to properly call this from the DARegisterDiskAppearedCallback line at the top.

```
-(void)diskAppearedCallback:(DADiskRef *)disk context:(void *)context{
    CFDictionaryRef description = DADiskCopyDescription(*disk);
    NSLog(@"Disk appeared: %@", description);

    NSString *spaceLeft = CFDictionaryGetValue(description, CFSTR("DADeviceModel"));

    NSLog(@"Disk Name: %@", CFDictionaryGetValue(description, CFSTR("DADeviceModel")));

    [labelSpaceLeft setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", spaceLeft]];


    CFRelease(description);
}
```

**UPDATE: Here is a gist of the project: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cb1c5795536ca15ef4e3

---

Comment: It's seriously using `assign` in that property?

Comment: Yes. I wouldn't know what it should be otherwise. This has been painful..

Comment: @Droppy aren't properties `assign` by default?  Could you post the full `undeclared identifier` error?

Comment: @MattyAyOh It depends on the property type; only primitive types are `assign`.

Comment: @Droppy but isn't the alternative `copy`?  What would an object be, by default then?

Comment: nvm, I see.  it's `assign` vs `weak`... but then I guess I don't really see how `strong` ties in anymore -.-

Comment: It says: Use of undeclared identifier '_labelSpaceLeft' .  Does't matter if I change it to just labelSpaceLeft. It's the same error, but with the identifier name changed.

Comment: What if you access labelSpaceLeft w/ self? (As you should be anyways).  i.e `self.labelSpaceLeft`

Comment: I added a gist of the project here: [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cb1c5795536ca15ef4e3). It's missing the xib, and an additional file or two, but this is the meat of the project.

Comment: @MattyAyOh the error then changes to Use of undeclared identifier 'self'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so the issue is that you are basically mixing C and Objective-C.  The callback function `diskAppearedCallback` is a C function and is not part of that class, even though it is defined between `@implementation` and `@end`.  It therefore doesn't have access to `_labelSpaceLeft`.

To fix the issue you need to get the callback function to call a method on that class instance, so when registering the callback, pass the instance in the last parameter.  This is precisely what context pointers are for in callback functions.

```
DARegisterDiskAppearedCallback(sessionDA,
     kDADiskDescriptionMatchVolumeMountable,
     diskAppearedCallback,
     self);    // HERE
```

and then `context` in the callback function will be a pointer to the class instance:

```
static void diskAppearedCallback(DADiskRef disk, void* context) {
    CFDictionaryRef description = DADiskCopyDescription(*disk);
    NSLog(@"Disk appeared: %@", description);

    NSString *spaceLeft = CFDictionaryGetValue(description, CFSTR("DADeviceModel"));

    NSLog(@"Disk Name: %@", CFDictionaryGetValue(description, CFSTR("DADeviceModel")));

    // HERE
    AVRecorderDocument *instance = (AVRecorderDocument *)context;
    [instance.labelSpaceLeft setStringValue:spaceLeft];


    CFRelease(description);
}
```

Comment: OK, maybe I've already tried what you're suggesting. I tried making a method "diskAppearedCallback", which is commented out in the gist at line 710.  That seemed to work fine, and I also declared? the method on line 30 in the same file. I just didn't know how to properly change the DARegisterDiskAppearedCallback callback to use the method

Comment: is the `diskAppearedCallback` a C method because it is defined w/ `static void `?

Comment: @MattyAyOh No, `static` just avoids the symbol being visible outside the implementation file.

Comment: OK, your latest edit makes perfect sense. I still have a hiccup with the DARegisterDiskAppearedCallback line though.  When I reference diskAppearedCallback in that line, the compiler is giving me a warning: Use of undeclared identifier 'diskAppearedCallback'. When I made the method before, I was getting that same error, and I couldn't figure out where to define that identifier.

Comment: That's because it needs to be declared at the top of the file, however that aspect has not changed from your original code; all I added was `self` rather than `0`.  Note that there was an error with the declaration of the callback function in my code; not sure how that happened.

Comment: Fixing the declaration fixed the issue. Thanks for all the help. This is what 15 years of php programming will do to you...